# With tabularray rowspec ,Q[f] does not Align cell at the foot. And how to remove caption?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularray

[image]

This is my code:

```
latex
% **************************************************
% Document Class
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,                   %
    11pt,                       % font size
]{scrreprt}    

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % define a new environment
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{long}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{  % set the default styles
colspec = {|
X[4.0cm,l]|
X[0.7cm,r]|
X[l]|
X[0.7cm,r]|
X[1.2cm,r]|
X[1.0cm,l]|},
width = 1.00\linewidth,
column{2,3,6} = {mode=dmath},
column{5} = {fg=blue},
rowspec={|
Q[h]|
Q[h]|
Q[m]|
Q[f]|
Q[f]|
Q[f]|}
}

\def\s{454}
\def\k{0.00394}
\def\treq{1.7886}

\begin{mytblr}[
  caption = {},
]{
  % more specs
}   
Factor
        & t_{req}
        & {= k \times  s \\ = \k \times  \s \\ = \treq}
        & t_{req}
        & 1.78876
        & \mathrm{mm} \\ 
\end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularray` relies on templates so you need to alter either the default one or declare and set a new template and then "bind" it with your table. For the demonstration, I created a template called `nocaptemplate`. This is applied to a custom theme `mytheme`, which in turn is applied to `mytblr`.

The bottom alignment can be achieved in multiple ways but appending `f` to last three column definitions worked for me.

There are errors in your code. For instance, you did not set math mode for the 4th column and use math expression `\t_{...}`. As to the multi-line contents, you tried to use `\\` inside a math environment. You need to use in-line math mode per each line and possibly turn off the math mode for that column or use multi-row environments, e.g. `aligned`; this is probably the most convenient approach.

Use `\newcommand` to create new macros instead of `\def...`, which warns you when you try to redefine existing macros.

If your table is supposed to span multiple pages, consider adding `rowhead = m` and or `rowfoot = n` which will copy the first `m` and the last `n` rows when spanning multiple pages.

[image]

```latex
% **************************************************
% Document Class
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
paper=A4,                   %
11pt,                       % font size
]{scrreprt}    

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% Removes captions
\DeclareTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % define a new environment
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{
  theme=mytabletheme,
  long,
}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{  % set the default styles
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {            
    X[5,l]             %<--- X only makes sense when using with proportions
    X[1,r]             %<--- Otherwise, behaves as a regular Q[...]
    X[5,l]
    X[1,r,f]
    X[2,r,f]
    X[2,l,f]
  },
  column{2-6} = {mode=dmath},
  column{5} = {fg=blue},
  hlines, vlines,
  % row{1,Z} = {font=\bfseries},  %<--- the first and the last row in bold 
  % rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1,     %<--- would copy the first/last column on subsequent pages
}


\begin{document}
\newcommand\vars{454}
\newcommand\vark{0.00394}
\newcommand\treq{1.7886}

\begin{mytblr}{}   
  Factor
  & t_{req}
  & \begin{aligned}[t]&= k \times s\\&= \vark \times \vars\\&= \treq\end{aligned}
  & t_{req}
  & 1.7887
  & \mathrm{mm} \\
\end{mytblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Your MWE is erroneous. At use of  `rowhead = {1}` table33 should have at least two rows!
- Does table is really long table? If not is simpler to stick with `tblr` table environment
- I suspect, that second and third column in your table are actually one column where in cells are `aligned` math. But I'm not sure, because you not provide any information what id other table rows.

See, if the following solution work for youČ

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\req}{req}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---

\def\s{454}
\def\k{0.00394}
\def\treq{1.7886}

\begin{longtblr}{
        rowhead = {1},
        colspec = {X[0.8, l] X[1.2, c] 
                   Q[f] Q[c, f, fg=blue] Q[f]},
        column{2,3} = {mode=dmath},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
        hline{1,2,Z} =1pt, hline{3-Y}=solid, vlines
                }
        & A & B & C & D         \\
Factor  & \begin{aligned}[t]
            t_{\req}    & = k \times    s \\ 
                        & = \k \times  \s \\ 
                        & = \treq
          \end{aligned}
            & t_{\req}
                & 1.78876
                    & mm    \\
text  & p_{\req} = 2\cdot\treq
            & p_{\req}
                & 3.57752
                    & mm    \\
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Now is inserted image produced with above MWE!

[image]