# Tabularray new template

Tags: templates, tabularray

I would like to customize the Tabularray "mytheme" for few more anomalous input options.

1. The Multi column input for comments in a simplified manner and
2. Fill column 3 for long equations preserving vertical alignment

By default I want one (1) vertical line with the results and comments on the right.

This is my code so far.

```
% **************************************************
% Document Class
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
paper=A4,                   %
11pt,                       % font size
]{scrreprt}    

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% Removes captions
\DeclareTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % define a new environment
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{
  theme=mytabletheme,
  long,
}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{  % set the default styles
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {            
    X[5,l]             %<--- X only makes sense when using with proportions
    X[1,r]             %<--- Otherwise, behaves as a regular Q[...]
    X[5,l]
    X[2,r,f]
    X[2,r,f]
    X[2,l,f]
  },
  column{2-6} = {mode=dmath},
  column{5} = {fg=blue},
  hlines, vlines,
  % row{1,Z} = {font=\bfseries},  %<--- the first and the last row in bold 
  % rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1,     %<--- would copy the first/last column on subsequent pages
}


\begin{document}
\newcommand\vart{3}
\newcommand\vars{454}
\newcommand\varp{4.54}
\newcommand\vark{0.00394}
\newcommand\varw{7.04}
\newcommand\vara{1.5}
\newcommand\varf{1.7886}
\newcommand\treq{2.94}

\begin{mytblr}{}   
    Factor
    & f
    & \begin{aligned}[t]&= k \times s\\&= \vark \times \vars\\&= \treq\end{aligned}
    & f=
    & \varf
    & \mathrm{mm} \\ [1em]
\SetCell[r=2]{l}
    Required thickness
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} t_{req}
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}
        \begin{aligned}[t]
    &= k \times  s \times \sqrt{\frac{p}{w}}+{a} \\
    & = \vark \times  \vars \times \sqrt{\frac{\varp}{\varw}}+{\vara} \\
    &= \treq\end{aligned}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l}
    {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    {[1]~{Chapter 11.1} \\
    $t_{req}<t$; OK} \\
    \end{tabular}} \\ 
    &
    &
    & t_{req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
\end{mytblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- your code contain errors, it can't be compiled
  -I would redefine your column specification ( yours are probably source of most of errors)
- in writing your table you should consider my answer on your previous question (to my taste it provide nicer result, but all is up to you)
- Anyway, tra the following:

```
\documentclass[
paper=A4,                   %
11pt,                       % font size
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,amssymb}

% Removes captions
\DeclareTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
}
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} % define a new environment
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{
  theme=mytabletheme,
  long,
}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]{  % set the default styles
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {
    X[l,h]
    Q[r,h, mode=math]
    X[3,l, mode=math]
    Q[r,f, mode=math]@{\;}
    Q[l,f, fg=blue]
    Q[l,f, mode=math]
  },
  vline{3}=1pt,
  rowsep=7pt
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\vart{3}
\newcommand\vars{454}
\newcommand\varp{4.54}
\newcommand\vark{0.00394}
\newcommand\varw{7.04}
\newcommand\vara{1.5}
\newcommand\varf{1.7886}
\newcommand\treq{2.94}

\begin{mytblr}{}
    Factor
    & f
    & \begin{aligned}[t]
        & = k \times s\\
        & = \vark \times \vars\\
        & = \treq
      \end{aligned}
    & f=
    & \varf
    & \mathrm{mm}   \\ 
    Required thickness
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} t_{req}
    & \SetCell[r=2]{c}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        & = k \times  s \times \sqrt{\frac{p}{w}}+{a} \\
        & = \vark \times  \vars \times \sqrt{\frac{\varp}{\varw}}+{\vara} \\
        & = \treq
    \end{aligned}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l, mode=text}  {[1] Chapter 11.1\\  
                    $t_{req}<t$; OK}
    &   
    &           \\
%%
    &
    &
    & t_{req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
\end{mytblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

- Based on my answer on your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661867/with-tabularray-rowspec-qf-does-not-align-cell-at-the-foot-and-how-to-remove) and corrected `\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}` ).
- **Edit:** to table isded is an example of use of the `multlined` environment (rows with them have gray bacground).

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}          % <--- added
\DeclareMathOperator{\req}{req} % <--- added
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% Removes captions
\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}
{
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead,
                 %firstfoot, middlefoot,lastfoot
                 }{default}{}%
} 
% define a new environment
\NewTblrEnviron{mytblr} 
\SetTblrOuter[mytblr]{theme=mytabletheme,long}
\SetTblrInner[mytblr]% set the default styles
{  
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {
    X[l,h]             
    X[3,l,h, mode=math]
    Q[r,f, mode=math]@{\;}
    Q[l,f, fg=blue]
    Q[l,f, mode=math]
  },
  vline{3}=1pt,
  rowsep=5pt
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\newcommand\vart{3}
\newcommand\vars{454}
\newcommand\varp{4.54}
\newcommand\vark{0.00394}
\newcommand\varw{7.04}
\newcommand\vara{1.5}
\newcommand\varf{1.7886}
\newcommand\treq{2.94}

\begin{mytblr}{}
Factor
    & \begin{aligned}[t]
    f & = k \times s\\
      & = \vark \times \vars\\
      &= \treq
     \end{aligned}
    & f=
    & \varf
    & \mathrm{mm}   \\ 
Required thickness
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    t_{req} & = k \times  s \times \sqrt{\frac{p}{w}}+{a} \\
            & = \vark \times  \vars \times \sqrt{\frac{\varp}{\varw}}+{\vara} \\
            & = \treq
    \end{aligned}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l, mode=text}  {[1] Chapter 11.1\\  
                    $t_{req}<t$; OK}
    &   
    &           \\
%%
    &
    & t_{req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
    
%%%%
Factor
    & \begin{aligned}[t]
    f & = k \times s\\
      & = \vark \times \vars\\
      &= \treq
     \end{aligned}
    & f=
    & \varf
    & \mathrm{mm}   \\
Required thickness
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    t_{req} & = k \times  s \times \sqrt{\frac{p}{w}}+{a} \\
            & = \vark \times  \vars \times \sqrt{\frac{\varp}{\varw}}+{\vara} \\
            & = \treq
    \end{aligned}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l, mode=text}  {[1] Chapter 11.1\\
                    $t_{req}<t$; OK}
    &
    &           \\
%%
    &
    & t_{req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
Factor
    & \begin{aligned}[t]
    f & = k \times s\\
      & = \vark \times \vars\\
      &= \treq
     \end{aligned}
    & f=
    & \varf
    & \mathrm{mm}   \\
%%%
    \SetRow{bg=gray!10}
use of multlined
     & \begin{multlined}[t]
        p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\
              - 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
    \end{multlined}
    & t_{req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
%%%
Required thickness
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    t_{\req} & = k \times  s \times \sqrt{\frac{p}{w}}+{a} \\
            & = \vark \times  \vars \times \sqrt{\frac{\varp}{\varw}}+{\vara} \\
            & = \treq
    \end{aligned}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l, mode=text}  {[1] Chapter 11.1\\
                    $t_{\req}<t$; OK}
    &
    &           \\
%%
    &
    & t_{\req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\    
    
    \SetRow{bg=gray!10}
use of multlined
     & \begin{multlined}[t]
        p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\
              - 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
    \end{multlined}
    & t_{req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
Factor
    & \begin{aligned}[t]
    f & = k \times s\\
      & = \vark \times \vars\\
      &= \treq
     \end{aligned}
    & f=
    & \varf
    & \mathrm{mm}   \\
    Required thickness
    & \SetCell[r=2]{l}
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    t_{\req} & = k \times  s \times \sqrt{\frac{p}{w}}+{a} \\
            & = \vark \times  \vars \times \sqrt{\frac{\varp}{\varw}}+{\vara} \\
            & = \treq
    \end{aligned}
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l, mode=text}  {[1] Chapter 11.1\\
                    $t_{\req}<t$; OK}
    &
    &           \\
%%
    &
    & t_{\req}=
    & \treq
    & \mathrm{mm} \\
\end{mytblr}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Above MWE produce two page long table. At bottom of first page is note *Continued on next page* (as is desired?)

[image]

Comment: Very nice! For equations longer than a line the multiline environment should be available. Such as, for example:

\begin{multiline*}
p(x) = 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\
- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{multiline*}

Comment: @PaulJGD, showed example will not work. You can't nested `multline*` inside math environment. For this you should use `multlined` of `mathtools` package. See edited addendum,